# Cognito WAF not matching AWS SDK request JSON body

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-waf

I have been configuring a Cognito User Pool to block certain requests from reaching out to Cognito and fail with a 403 Forbidden error, for that I have enabled Cognito WAF and created a Web ACL with the following rule:

- Rule name: block-json-payload

  - Type: regular rule
  - If a request: matches the statement
  - Inspect: body
  - Content Type: JSON
  - JSON Match Scope: Values
  - How AWS WAF should treat invalid requests: match
  - Content to inspect: Only Included Elements

    - /AuthParameters/USERNAME
  - Match Type: contains string
  - String to match: mydomain.com
  - Oversize handling: match
  - Action: block

I also set the Web ACL default termination to be allow.

That should mean that whenever a request is made to Cognito containing the follow JSON body it should block.

```json
{
  "AuthFlow": "CUSTOM_AUTH",
  "ClientId": "xxxxxxxx",
  "AuthParameters": {
    "USERNAME": "xxxx@mydomain.com",
    "SRP_A": "abc...",
    "CHALLENGE_NAME": "SRP_A"
  },
  "ClientMetadata": {}
}
```

Because this request goes via Cognito SDK and contains the following Headers, specially content-type: `application/x-amz-json-1.1`, I assume Web ACL can't handle that. Does that mean that if the content type is not `application/json` this Web ACL Rule will be skipped? Besides, how can I validate requests that are effectively JSON, like this one, but that don't come with the correct content-type?

Request:

```js
fetch('https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/', {
  'headers': {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'no-store',
    'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="119", "Chromium";v="119", "Not?A_Brand";v="24"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'x-amz-target': 'AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth',
    'x-amz-user-agent': 'aws-amplify/5.0.4 js'
  },
  'referrer': 'https://xxxxxx.com/',
  'referrerPolicy': 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
  'body': '{"AuthFlow":"CUSTOM_AUTH","ClientId":"xxx","AuthParameters":{"USERNAME":"xxxx@mydomain.com","SRP_A":"abc...","CHALLENGE_NAME":"SRP_A"},"ClientMetadata":{}}',
  'method': 'POST',
  'mode': 'cors',
  'credentials': 'omit'
});
```

Note:

Although [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-statement-fields-list.html#waf-rule-statement-request-component-json-body) mentions the Content Type parameter configuration as JSON, is not clear if the HTTP Header Conten-Type must be `application/json` or it could be any other value as long as the body is parsable to JSON.